# Getopt code segfaults when compiling with -O3 on OS X Mavericks

Tags: c, optimization, segmentation-fault, getopt

I noticed recently that some programs I have written (using libgetopt) segfault when given an argument starting with a double-dash e.g. `--help`.

I managed to reproduce this with the following small program:

```
#include <getopt.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Parse arguments.
    struct option long_options[] = {
        { "test", required_argument, 0, 't' }
    };
    int option_index, arg;
    while((arg = getopt_long(argc, argv, "t:", long_options, &option_index)) != -1);

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this with `./a.out --help` it works fine. But as soon as I compile using `-O3` it segfaults. This behaviour is observed using Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) on OS X Mavericks (10.9).

Is there anything I can do to fix this, or should I just refrain from using `-O3` in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the man page for getopt_long

```
 The last element of the longopts array has to be filled with zeroes.
```

So what you need is another line

```
struct option long_options[] = {
    { "test", required_argument, 0, 't' },
    { 0 } // this line is new
};
```

I suspected this was the case because I looked at your code and asked, "how does getopt_long know how many elements is in the array". man page confirmed.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Guess I really should've RTFM properly. Any idea why it worked without the optimization? I'm looking at the difference in the generated assembly now but I'm having trouble finding why it works in the unoptimized version.

Comment: First guess would be padding zeros to next major alignment; with space optimization that might get used for something.